# how to open another popup from popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I want to create a automated test case which involves the launching of popup(e.g. PopB) from another popup(e.g. PopA).

I got the popup(PopA) by using the following code:

```
selenium.windowFocus();
selenium.waitForPopUp("PopupDialog", "60000");
selenium.selectWindow("PopupDialog");
selenium.selectFrame("PopupDialog");
```

But after 60 seconds, the whole application crashed with "Timed out" exception. I want to launch the second popup(PopB) on the onclick of button present on popup(PopA).

Is it possible to achieve the requirement? If yes, then please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve that. Follow steps like below

- selenium.windowFocus();
- selenium.waitForPopUp("PopupDialogA", "60000");
- selenium.selectWindow("PopupDialogA");
- selenium.selectFrame("PopupDialogA");
- click("Button in popup A");
- selenium.windowFocus();
- selenium.waitForPopUp("PopupDialogB", "60000");
- selenium.selectWindow("PopupDialogB");
- selenium.selectFrame("PopupDialogB");
- close popup B
- switch back to popup A
- close popup A
- switch back to main window

Comment: Hi Santoshsarma, thanks for the reply. I have tried your suggestion but still application is crashing after 60 seconds(of PopupDialogA).

Comment: Is it clicking button in popup-A. Just add some debug statements and see up to what it is executing? Is it properly switch the control to popup-A?

Answer (score 0):

Another method i think may work. Not tested... but worth looking at..

```
<a href="http://foo.com" onclick="javascript:void window.open('http://foo.com','1412867400701','width=940,height=620,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,left=50,top=80');return false;">Foo</a><br/>
```

and in the next window..

```
<a href="http://bar.com" onclick="javascript:void window.open('http://bar.com','1412867400702','width=840,height=460,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,left=30,top=50');return false;">Bar</a>
```

Change **1412867400701** and **1412867400702** to different numbers should do the trick..
  Like i said... not tested... but theory works...